# New and Just Installed Ubuntu.... But my Memory Usage messed up

Tags: hard-drive

Ussing an old Laptop and things so far look like they are running well. Again It's only a few hours now.

Anyway... Here is what my Details say:

> Memory : 1.9 GB
>   System Type :32 Bit
>   HD SIZE 77.8 GB

Is this telling me I only have 1.9 GB left?

I just installed this over Windows so everything should be gone... should be plenty of HD left not 1.9 GB.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1.9gb should be the ram

Answer (score 2):

1.9 Gb should be the RAM Memory

Type
`df -h` to know your disk space usage and paste it on [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the link here.

Comment: Well I feel better...so far...

Comment: @ByByWindows So you have a 2 GB ram, Right?

Comment: i know stupid question but no idea.. Where do I type df -h?

Comment: yes 2gb... old laptop that im playing on

Comment: @ByByWindows So your problem is fixed! :)

Comment: Moot point, but you would type `df -h` in the terminal, press the start key and type terminal to launch.  You could also hit alt+F2 and type it in the resulting window, or type in the window from ctrl+alt+t.  The possibilities are endless! =D